# Finding the limit of roots products $(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[4]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[5]{2})\cdot \cdot \cdot (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2})$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinite-product

I need to find:

> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty } (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[4]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[5]{2})\cdot \cdot \cdot (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2}) 
> $$

So far, I think that $0<\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2}<1$, and it seems to me that the limit will approach zero but I can't figure how to show it mathematically.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551301/find-the-limit-without-using-the-squeezing-principle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[4]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[5]{2})\cdot \cdot \cdot (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2}) \leq (\sqrt{2}-1)^{n-2} $$ and clearly 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } (\sqrt{2}-1)^{n-2} =0$$

since $0<(\sqrt{2}-1)<1$

so by the comparison test we win.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I got my inequalities messed up, it is fixed now. For whatever reason my sleep-deprived mind had trouble realizing it needed to make the terms being subtracted as small as possible not as big as possible.

Comment: Its Ok @PVAL. It happens to all of us quite a few times :)

Comment: how did you think about $(\sqrt{2}-1)^{n-2}$?

Comment: I saw that each term in the product was less than some given number $<1$ , so I tried (unsuccessfully at first) to come up with a number that worked. The $n-2$ is really just from counting the number of terms.

Comment: Got it. thanks a lot!

Comment: very nice!thax..

Answer (score 7):

$(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[4]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[5]{2})\cdot \cdot \cdot (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2}) \leq (\sqrt{2}-1)^{n-2}$, done.

Comment: How did you come up with the inequality?