# What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt2-\sqrt[3]2)\cdots(\sqrt2-\sqrt[n]2)$? How to approach?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt2-\sqrt[3]2)(\sqrt2-\sqrt[4]2)(\sqrt2-\sqrt[5]2)\cdots(\sqrt2-\sqrt[n]2)$$

Could you tell me how to approach this kind of question? How do I find the limit of this sequence?

I know that for very large $n$ the each bracket is more than $1$, so my guess is its going to infinity, how do I prove such a thing?

Comment: What happens when you compare this limit to $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt 2-\sqrt[n]{2})^n$?  What is the numeric value of $\sqrt 2-1$?

Comment: this will obviously go to infinity as each bracket is more then 1 to the power of n, but thats not the original sequence was...

Comment: I think you have overestimated the value of $\sqrt 2 -1$...

Comment: oops, i got it, using the sandwich theorem i can prove that the series you provided is approaching 0 that proves it, right?

Comment: That is correct :-)

Comment: @user1333057 Trivial comment for you: that's the limit of an expression, not an equation (which is a thing with an equals in it).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452173/finding-the-limit-of-roots-products-sqrt2-sqrt32-sqrt2-sqrt42

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Formally, we can say that $\sqrt 2\gt\sqrt[3]2\gt\sqrt[4]2\gt\dots\gt\sqrt[n]2\gt 1$ as $n\to\infty$, and $0\lt\sqrt 2-\sqrt[3] 2\lt\sqrt 2-\sqrt[4] 2\lt\dots\lt\sqrt 2-\sqrt[n] 2\lt\sqrt 2-1\lt \frac 12,$ therefore

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=3}^n(\sqrt 2-\sqrt[i] 2)\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 12\right)^n=0$$