# Find the limit of $(\sqrt2-\root3\of2 )(\sqrt2 -\root4\of2 )...(\sqrt 2-\root{n}\of2 )$ without using the squeezing principle

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } (\sqrt 2  - \root 3 \of 2 )(\sqrt 2  - \root 4 \of 2 )...(\sqrt 2  - \root n \of 2 )$$

I was able easily to find the limit of this series using the squeezing principle, but how can you find it without it? I'm guessing it's an algebra trick :)

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is not a good fit for this questions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info).

Comment: In this case, the answer to that other question implicitly uses the squeeze theorem, though it calls it the comparison test. @MartinSleziak

Comment: It seems that I was too quick on the trigger @ThomasAndrews. I am voting to reopen in that case.

Comment: Other questions about the same limit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452173/finding-the-limit-of-roots-products-sqrt2-sqrt32-sqrt2-sqrt42, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549111/what-is-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrt2-sqrt32-cdots-sqrt2-sqrtn2-ho

Answer (score 4):

I see no trick nor algebra, just the simple observation that for every $k \geq 3$ we have $2^{1/2} > 2^{1/k} > 1$, so that
$$
0 \leq \prod_{k=3}^n \left(2^{1/2}-2^{1/k}\right) \leq \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{n-2}
$$
The r.h.s. being a geometric sequence with $0 < \sqrt{2} - 1 < 1$, the sequence converges (very quickly) towards $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Our sequence is $a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (2^{1/2}-2^{1/k}).$
Take the log to get
$$\log(a_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \log(2^{1/2}-2^{1/k}).$$
This is a typical thing to do when you have a product. Note that for $k$ large $2^{1/2}-2^{1/k}$ is near $\sqrt{2}-1$ and $\log(\sqrt{2}-1)<0$. Thus the series diverges and $\log(a_n) \to -\infty$. This means $a_n \to 0$.