# How I compute $(2-\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt[3]{2})\cdots(2-\sqrt[n]{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

The product has only positive factors so it has zero as lower bound. Also the product is decreasing as all its factors are less than one. In conclusion the series must have a limit. I also compute the first 100 values of the product and I got around 0.03. I also look at link but I can't use the same trick. –

I am pretty sure that the limit is zero but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Please do not have the entire question in the title, but rather in the post. As is, this is a [problem statement](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so please consider reading [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [edit] accordingly. Taking from the good question guide: Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader. You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: But thanks for using MathJax.

Comment: The series has positive values so it has zero as lower bound. Also the serie is decreasing so it must have a limit. I also compute the first 100  values of the product and I got around 0.03. I also look at [link]( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452173/finding-the-limit-of-roots-products-sqrt2-sqrt32-sqrt2-sqrt42) but I can't use the same trick.

Comment: @motoras Consider adding this info into the question it seems really helpful   and will hopefully stop the down votes/close votes.

Comment: Try to show that $2-2^{1/n} \leq 2^{-1/n}$

Comment: Call $a_n$ that number. Then $\ln(a_n)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\ln\left(1+(1-e^{\ln(2)/k}\right)$. We can compare this series to $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ taking into account that $\ln(1-x)/x\to-11$ and $(1-e^{x})/x\to-1$ as $x\to0$. Therefore $\ln(a_n)$ diverges to $-\infty$. Therefore $a_n=e^{\ln(a_n)}\to0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the arithmetic mean is greater than or equal to the geometric mean, we know that
$$
\frac{2^{1/n}+2^{-1/n}}{2} \geq \sqrt{2^{1/n}\cdot 2^{-1/n}} = 1
$$
Therefore $2-2^{1/n} \leq 2^{-1/n}$ and
$$
(2-2^{1/2})(2-2^{1/3})\cdot \ldots \cdot (2-2^{1/n})
\leq 
2^{-\left( \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} +\ldots +\frac{1}{n} \right) }
$$
As the harmonic series diverges, the limit of the original product is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer I want it.  I got to the same answer after you gave me the clue.  I did prove that $$2-2^{1/n} \leq 2^{-1/n}  using
a/b+b/a>=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) $\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ (with $a_n > 0$) converges to a nonzero value if and only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(a_n)$ converges.